# gnome window positioning shortcuts

Tags: gnome, window-manager

With multiple monitors, multiple windows I find sometimes I have to click and drag windows, resize them and spend a bit of effort to get them positioned the way I would like.

Is there any shortcuts to doing this?

Perhaps a way to have some default setup where windows are opened and positioned properly, or a shortcut to make any window a certain size?

For example, I usually have at least one or two terminals open, a file browser of some sort, at least one editor and a browser.  What I would like is maybe a browser open full screen on one monitor, and then on the other my editor split vertically with 2 terminals split horizontally beside the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Devil's Pie](http://live.gnome.org/DevilsPie)

Comment: Awesome, this looks simply great.